# SSRS hosted on SharePoint 2013 Export to Excel unable to open the exported Excel file

Tags: reporting-services

We have a SSRS Report hosted on SharePoint 2013.
The problem is when we export it in Excel and try to open it Excel gives us an Error that "Excel found unreadable content in this file".
Strange part is that it works fine in the other Environment which is also pointing to the same DB in back end for that SSRS Report.
It seems that in the other Environment Excel export service is able to convert the unreadable data which in our case is an "->" in one of the columns.
We need to understand which service is used to export SSRS data to Excel then we can compare both the Environments and find out the difference.